How to add type inference to Python Flask and Marshmallow
I'm new to Python from a Typescript background. Putting together a Flask API server and using Marshmallow to validate input DTOs.
How can I get VSCode to infer types from the Marshmallow Schema load?
class PostInput:
    myString = fields.Str(
        required=True
    )

@app.route('/foo', methods=['POST'])
def post_foo():
    try:
        data = PostInput().load(request.json)
    except ValidationError as err:
        return jsonify(err.messages), 400
      
    myString = data.get("myString")

    myString <== I want this to be known as a str


Hi, very much depends on your goal. Marshmallow by default serialise data to a dict and you can't specify types for each key and value for the default python dict. Thus easiest solution would be to help Python to understand what is the myString key data types: myString: str = data.get("myString")

Adding typing hint to the dict key:
from marshmallow import fields, Schema

class PostInput(Schema):
    myString = fields.Str(
        required=True
    )
    
json = '{"myString": "hello"}'
data = PostInput().loads(json, many=False)
myString:str = data.get("myString")

or serializing data into the dataclass:

from marshmallow import fields, Schema, post_load
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class InputClass:
    myString: str


class PostInput(Schema):
    myString = fields.Str(
        required=True
    )
    @post_load
    def make_user(self, data, **kwargs) -> InputClass:
        return InputClass(**data)
        
    
json = '{"myString": "hello"}'
data: InputClass = PostInput().loads(json, many=False)
myString = data.myString

I would recommend to use pydantic for validation and loading the json. It does both validates the data and creates smth like a dataclass that inherits types of the attributes:
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field

class PostInput(BaseModel):
    myString: str = Field(required=True)    

json = '{"myString": "hello"}'
data = PostInput.model_validate_json(json)
myString = data.myString


I think Pydantic is the way forward for any TS peeps landing here, it's the most similar to Class Validator and Class Transformer.
